# inputHidden binding to a long id field in backing bean

Tags: jsf-2

Just wondering how to set a hidden field value so that when I submit my form, JSF sets it as the id in an object in my CDI-managed bean.

My bean is called "discussionManager" and it has an object in it called 'discussion', which is an entity and therefore has an ID of type Long.

I need the ID so I can look it up and do stuff with it. But, JSF doesn't seem to like numeric hidden fields. It is fine with string fields though. Sure it has something to do with converters or the binding attribute, but can't get the syntax. This is what I'm trying in it's simplest form.

```
<h:inputHidden id="discussionId" value="#{viewDiscussionBean.discussion.id}"/>
```

I've tried lots of variations. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to explicitly specify a converter. The JSF builtin [`LongConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/LongConverter.html) is suitable.

```
<h:inputHidden id="discussionId" value="#{viewDiscussionBean.discussion.id}" converter="javax.faces.Long" />
```

Comment: Oh, I was trying with javax.faces.convert.LongConverter. I saw your version on another post and couldn't find any docs on it so assumed it was wrong, then looked at the packages hence what I came up with. I'll try it out and (when my server finally comes back to life and tested it) will post back. Thanks

Comment: In the `LongConverter` Javadoc, check `CONVERTER_ID` constant. It's exactly that converter ID value: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.LongConverter.CONVERTER_ID

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful to know. I suck at JSF, I'm trying though lol :)

Comment: It works! (I had to refactor a load of my other code before I could test it, as my architecture was a mess). That works great though. Thanks